# How to make an input fit nicely inside a cell in a CellTable?

Tags: css, gwt, celltable

[image: GWT CellTable]

In the screenshot above the input width exceeds the column width. How to make it fit perfectly inside a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS file:

```
td input[type="text"], td select {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. It works as expected. :) http://stackoverflow.com/users/821657/andrei-volgin

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your other columns a high width value such as 45% on the other two colums. The remaining column will then be 10% (max) but will alway fit the data within it.